# jQuery validation for textbox and Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form in "jQuery Dialog Box" and in which there is a `<textarea>` and the other is a pair of `<input type="radio" />` buttons

Both are required fields and if the user leaves the testarea empty or do not check any of the radio , the user should get the message and the Dialog box should not close.

I have tried doing the validation, its working for Textarea but not for the radio buttons.

Here is the Fiddle I created : **http://jsfiddle.net/JLDf5/**

Here is the code for the same:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sessionReason" title="End Transaction">
    <p class="validation-summary-errors marginBottom10">Provide the following information to proceed:</p>
    <div class="marginBottom" id="sessionDocumentMessage">
        <label class="marginBottom5 marginTop10">Return the document?</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Return</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Keep</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="marginBottom5" id="sessionReasonMessage">Reason for ending the transaction:</p>
    <textarea id="sessionReasonBox" class="reasonBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
$("#sessionReason").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "End Transaction": function () {
            var sessionReasonBox = $("#sessionReasonBox").val();
            if ($('[name="sessionDocuments"]').is(':checked')){
                $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
                $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").addClass("redtext");
            }
            if (sessionReasonBox == "") {
                $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
                $("#sessionReasonMessage").addClass("redtext");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
                $("#sessionReasonMessage").removeClass("redtext");
            }
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with the below code:

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6xY4B/)**

Below is the Code for the same

---

**HTML**

```
<input class="redButton" id="openDialogButton" type="button" value="Open Dialog">
<div id="sessionReason" title="End Transaction">
    <p class="validation-summary-errors marginBottom10">Provide the following information to proceed:</p>
    <div class="marginBottom" id="sessionDocumentMessage">
        <label class="marginBottom5 marginTop10">Return the document?</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Return</label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Keep</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p class="marginBottom5" id="sessionReasonMessage">Reason for ending the transaction:</p>
    <textarea id="sessionReasonBox" class="reasonBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function showValidationError() {
    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
}

function hideValidationError() {
    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
}

function addRadioError() {
    $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").addClass("redtext");
}

function removeRadioError() {
    $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").removeClass("redtext");
}

function addReasonBoxError() {
    $("#sessionReasonMessage").addClass("redtext");

}

function removeReasonBoxError() {
    $("#sessionReasonMessage").removeClass("redtext");
}

$('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
$("#sessionReason").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "End Transaction": function () {
            var enteredReason = $('#sessionReasonBox').val();
            var radioChecked = $("#sessionReason input:radio[name='sessionDocuments']:checked");

            if ((enteredReason.length <= 0) && (radioChecked.length == 0)) {
                //Show Error
                showValidationError();
                addReasonBoxError();
                addRadioError();
                //Hide Validation Error
            } else if ((enteredReason.length > 0) && (radioChecked.length == 0)) {
                //Show Validation Error
                showValidationError();
                addRadioError();
                //Hide Validation Error
                removeReasonBoxError();
            } else if ((enteredReason.length <= 0) && (radioChecked.length > 0)) {
                //Show Validation Error
                showValidationError();
                addReasonBoxError();
                //Hide Validation Error
                removeRadioError();
            } else {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                //Hide Validation Error
                hideValidationError();
                removeRadioError();
                removeReasonBoxError();
            }
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});



$("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
    $('#sessionReasonBox').val("");
    $('#sessionDocumentMessage input:radio').removeAttr('checked');
    $("#sessionReason").dialog("open");
    //Hide Validation Error
    hideValidationError();
    removeRadioError();
    removeReasonBoxError();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF blocks needs ELSE IF and the close should be inside the IF block. and check for ! (not) radio checked. and no need return false.

```
 if (!$('[name="sessionDocuments"]').is(':checked')){
    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
    $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").addClass("redtext");
 }
 else if (sessionReasonBox == "") {
    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
    $("#sessionReasonMessage").addClass("redtext");
    //return false;
 }
 else {
    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
    $("#sessionReasonMessage").removeClass("redtext");
    $(this).dialog("close");
 }
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLDf5/1/)